# Despite multiprocessing, the program is still blocked

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I got an application (GUI: wxPython).
When I click on a tree item, the application will do something.
But in this time the rest of the application is blocked until the task is done.
It's ok because the execution runs in the same process.

Now I transfered the execution in a separate process (with multiprocessing module)
I expected that the program is not longer blocked during the task execution.
But it is still blocked. :(

```
def Click(self, event):
# ....
# collect some data and create 
# mytask = [.....]
 p = Process(target=taskexecution.run, args=(mytask,))
 p.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try what happens if you use `p.start()` instead.

Comment: I was totally thinking in the wrong direction: @bob morane: you are indeed still running the function in the main process by using `run` instead of `start`. Consider my answer some background info on properly updating your GUI: this one will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use thread-safe methods when running multiple processes in WxPython. How to handle this is very clearly and thoroughly explained in this [Mouse vs Python blog post](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/).